# What is the current status of the WebCL implementation on major browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, webcl

I have this question because I cant find official information from Google, Mozilla or Microsoft. I just found 2014 dated entries. I would like that kind of efficiency on the browser.

To the moderator: Please keep this question while as its answer evolve with time.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this can be a good question since there's no reasonable way to answer it in a form where any particular answer is useful in e.g. 6 months time.

Comment: Is useful if we keep this updated. While browsers starts to support it. Dont you think? I asked because I genuinely didnt knew, but I was afraid that no browser vendor has production implementation.

Comment: Does that mean we should make it a Community Wiki?

Answer (score 4):

The latest Version of the spec is (in June 2016) still  in "draft"-status: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webcl/specs/latest/1.0/

No browser vendor seems to have implemented it or even having concrete plans to implement it at the moment.

For performance-intensive calculations WebAssembly is currently probably the better horse to place a bet on: http://webassembly.github.io/