# How does OpenBLAS support vectors and matrices of arbitrary sizes?

Tags: x86, x86-64, blas, openblas

I'm trying to understand [what it takes to support fast vectorized linear algebra computations for matrices and vectors of arbitrary size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917578/does-browser-javascript-allow-for-simd-or-vectorized-operations). From what I understand about the x86 processor architectures, they contain [special registers of limited size](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Advanced_Vector_Extensions). These registers allow for floating point numbers to be loaded and operations to be broadcast across the registers. How do you get around the limited size efficiently?

I was looking at the OpenBLAS source code to figure this out, but despite looking at the [dev docs](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/Developer-manual), couldn't figure out the general flow for a simple operation such as `gemv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenBLAS relies on kernels to perform these operations efficiently. In this context, a "kernel" is assembly code specifically written for a linear algebra operation. For example, see these kernels for [x86-64](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/kernel/x86_64/cgemv_n.S) and [ARM64](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/master/kernel/arm64/gemv_t.S) for the `gemv` operation.